# assembly include irvine on win10 //bootcamp

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

my laptop is mac pro i7
I have assembly course this semester and I have to working on VS2022
so I install windows through bootcamp win10  and install vs2022
when I write any code with .model flat// .386 ...ets it shows syntax error
and when I include address of irvine32.inc library then call foe example `call writeString`
it is error (undefined symbol)
literally I saw every tutorial about include irvine..setmasm..etc
but it is still errors code

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

INCLUDElib  C :\Users\atpc\Downloads\Irvine\Irvine\irvine32.inc

ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword

.data
 msg byte "hello world",0

 .code
main proc
    mov edx,offset msg
    call writeString

    call  ExitProcess,0

main endp
end main
```

the above code shows theses errors:

[image]

Comment: `Irvine32.inc` is not a library, it is an include file. Change `includelib` to `include`. You may then run into this issue (see solution): https://stackoverflow.com/q/73822590/3857942

Comment: Something else I just noticed. The message at the bottom says it is running ml64.exe. ml64.exe is the 64-bit assembler and it will not be able to assemble this 32-bit code. You will need to target x86 (not x86-64) so that the 32-bit assembler `ml.exe` will be invoked.

Comment: if i change includelib to include error says file(parh\irvine.inc)  cannot be opend A1000

Comment: last error I change it to 86 the error just change ml64.exe to ml.exe

Comment: Well make sure the path is correct. In particular make sure it does not have the space in it that is included in your question.

Comment: What Jester is referring to is that in the include line you put a space between `C` and the `:`  . You used C : where it should be C:

Comment: good it works but unfortunately the error  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WriteString@0 referenced in function _main@0 ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\atpc\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\main.obj 1 
raised !! is it beacuse the file is in downloads !

Comment: You need to add an `INCLUDELIB` for the `.lib` file, or add that in the linker options.

Comment: thank u sooo much! i just reload and check the specific path it works (tomorrow I have lab quiz )